# Reduce power output of 240V Ac supply by high resistor?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, resistors

Main supply of 240V socket and connect in series with a very high resistor and a mini 5V 2A (AC motor). The reason is the high resistor would absorb a lot of the power supplied by the main 240V socket so that there will be a smaller power supplied to the AC motor otherwise burnt up. Wouldn't it be inefficient since power in=power out and I am just wasting electricity on that resistor. What would be an alternative way of reducing the power supplied by the 240V socket efficiently and extract the power that I needed from the socket? Is it safe to connect a very high resistor to a 240V power supply?

Comment: Specs/datasheet for the mini 5V 2A (AC motor)!  This is a strange voltage for an ac motor!

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use a 5 V AC output transformer, preferrably one in a wall wart / plugtop configuration, CE marked for safety. This will draw from the mains only the power it needs to supply the motor (10 watts) plus a bit for its own inefficiency (say 2 watts). That's a current consumption of around 50 mA at 240 V, for 5 V 2 A output, while it gets slightly warm.

There are components other than resistors that can be used to provide a constant current (ish) supply from a high voltage AC input without wasting power, an inductor, or a capacitor. Although not getting as hot as a resistor, these would be just as dangerous to use directly connected to mains, with extra hazards in addition to those of a resistor due to their energy storage capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

> *240V socket and connect in series with a very high resistor and a mini
> 5V 2A (\$\color{red}{\text{AC motor}}\$)*

If the motor is taking 2 amps (as per the details in your question) then 2 amps will flow through the dropper resistor and 235 volts (approximately) will be across the dropper resistor. That's a resistance of 117.5 Ω and a power dissipation of 470 watts. This isn't a tiny resistor by any means.

> *Is it safe to connect a very high resistor to a 240V power supply?*

Well, the resistance isn't very high and the power dissipation isn't that high (in some circles of engineering) so, providing you use an appropriately rated resistor that is suitable for connection across 240 volts live and neutral AND it's segregated from accidental touch and has some warning labels on it, then I guess it's safe.

It's not a very good idea but, you didn't ask that.

> *What would be an alternative way of reducing the power supplied by the
> 240V socket efficiently and extract the power that I needed from the
> socket?*

Use a step-down transformer of power rating around 15 VA.

Comment: @Andy aka, then if i cannot do that way, how can I extract the power required from my 240V socket? I dont know how mobile phone charger did it. However, using a transformer also would not reduce the power since power in=power out. So, how do these tiny mobile phone chargers did it which extract the only the power required by the charger? Thank you

Comment: @MaximusSu a transformer sure would work - it'll have a power transfer efficiency of 95% or above. No problem using a transformer.

Comment: Hi sir, but it will still extract tremendous amount of power from the socket because transformer principle is (power in=power out), it would have burn the motor

Comment: @MaximusSu you shouldn't argue with someone who knows all about transformers. The power out will be around 10 watts and therefore the power in will be about 10 or 11 watts. The power into the transformer is determined by the power out and the transformer's efficiency.

Comment: But a transformer will still extract tremendous amount of power from the source right? I am not talking about efficiency

Comment: `But a transformer will still extract tremendous amount of power from the source right?` Wrong. A transformer will extract the power it needs for the output to the motor, 10 watts, plus the power it wastes in its losses, a watt or two, so 12 watts give or take. That's 50 mA current draw from the 240 V mains (12 watts in), delivering 2 A to the motor at 5 V (10 watts to the motor), while it burns 2 watts just being a small transformer.

Comment: @Neil_UK, so a transformer will extract the power that it needs, you mean to say that if I connect a 50 coils input and a 50 coils output transformer, it will light up an LED without bursting it because I have seen in some videos of them connecting LED to socket using this transformer method and burst it?

Comment: @MaximusSu What's a '50 coils input' transformer? If you want to connect a transformer to 240 V mains, it would need to be physically very big indeed to be running with a 50 turn primary, perhaps 100 kg or more. A typical 20 VA transformer would have 5000 turns in the primary. I'm sure you can burst an LED by connecting it to something that can deliver too much power, there's all sorts of destructive nonsense on youtube.

Comment: @Neil_UK So, you are saying is if transformer has 5000 turns in the primary and 5000 turns in secondary, it will maybe light up an LED without bursting?

Comment: @MaximusSu transformers are used all over the AC distribution system from generators to extra high voltage overhead lines and back down to 11 kV substations and then to your street. If each transformer wasted over 95% of the throughput we produce then we would have a much more serious global warming problem and, each transformer would need to be the size of a small European country to prevent it exploding. Listen to what the experts say.

Comment: @MaximusSu if it had 5k turns on both pri and sec, then it would output roughly its input, 240 V, and would burst a LED. You don't light a LED stably by connecting it to a) a voltage source and b) an AC supply. You connect it to a DC current source of the correct value. If OTOH you want to make a youtube video of things exploding, you can connect anything to anything, and if it goes bang, then result, advertising revenue.

Comment: @MaximusSu "but it will still extract tremendous amount of power from the socket" – No, that's not true. "But a transformer will still extract tremendous amount of power from the source right?" – Nope, not true. "you mean to say that if I connect a 50 coils input and a 50 coils output transformer, it will light up an LED without bursting it" – No, still not true. "you are saying is if transformer has 5000 turns in the primary and 5000 turns in secondary, it will maybe light up an LED without bursting?" – No, that's not correct, either.

Comment: @MaximusSu You might be confusing voltage with power. Maybe you think that 240 V is a large amount of power. That's not true, because 240 V isn't *any* amount of power. Power isn't measured in volts. It's totally possible for a transformer to draw a tiny amount of power from a 240 V outlet and to pass that power on to an LED. The LED will consume that tiny amount of power, and it will (perhaps) light up without being damaged.

Comment: @MaximusSu That said, a transformer with 5000 turns in the primary and 5000 turns in the secondary, with an LED connected to the secondary, _will_ draw a huge amount of power from a 240 V outlet, and it will pass all that power to the LED, and the LED will be destroyed.

Comment: @MaximusSu You might have heard somebody say, "Electronic devices extract whatever amount of power they need." That's sometimes true, but it's sometimes false. An electronic device only does that if it's designed to do that. Furthermore, an electronic device only does that if it's used in the manner in which it's designed to be used. If you connect a 120 V desk lamp to a 120 V outlet, then the desk lamp will draw the amount of power that it needs, because the desk lamp is designed to do that, and you're using the desk lamp the way it's designed to be used.

Comment: @MaximusSu If you connect an LED to a 240 V outlet, then it the LED will _not_ draw the amount of power that it needs, because an LED is not designed to do that, and you're not using the LED the way it was designed to be used. The LED will draw much more power than it needs and it'll be destroyed. If you add a 5000:5000 transformer, the same thing will happen.

Comment: @TannerSwett - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However your 5 (!) comments are *answering* the OP, which is not an [allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Please consider moving those comments into your own answer, to save the mods the work of having to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Always try to avoid dealing with AC mains

Converting from AC mains voltage to low voltage is a *solved problem*. You shouldn't re-invent the wheel, because the COTS products already on the market are safety certified.  And yours won't be.

As it works out, approved 2 amp 5 volt power supplies are extremely common.  In my country they are sold at every gas station and convenience store.  They are more easily found *than eggs*.

### That doesn't mean not having fun

However if you wanted a bit more of an adventure, you could pick any approved wall-wart power supply that makes 6-15 volts AC or DC, and then play with different ways to condition that power to the 5VAC that you need.  You or your friends probably have tons of them in your junk drawer from old consumer products.

From the safe low voltage source, you can try different methods to get the voltage and frequency that you need.

Comment: Of course,I have tried using like my phone charger, but the maximum amount of power it can deliver is restricted. What charger can give such a high power need?

Comment: @MaximusSu Chargers for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to connect a very high resistor to a 240V power supply?

**No**.

1. The mains is AC. Your motor is DC.
2. The mains voltage is high. A 5 V motor's insulation will not be rated for mains voltage.
3. The motor would have to be considered live since it is connected to mains.
4. Even if you could use AC to power it, the motor consumes 5 V × 2 A = 10 W. Your resistor would have to drop 235 V × 2A = 470 W. It would be like a room heater.
5. When the motor is unloaded the current required will decrease. That means the current through the resistor would decrease. That means that the voltage across the resistor would decrease. That means that the voltage across the motor would increase beyond the 5 V rating.
6. The motor should be fed with a constant 5 V or less.

Try using a 5 V, 2 A mobile phone power supply (usually referred to as a "charger"). They give a steady 5 V and are isolated from the mains. They're cheap.

Comment: The op says the motor is AC. Whether he's correct, is another matter.

Comment: @Transistor, then if i cannot do that way, how can I extract the power required from my 240V socket? I dont know how mobile phone charger did it. However, using a transformer also would not reduce the power since power in=power out. So, how do these tiny mobile phone chargers did it which extract the only the power required by the charger? Thank you

Comment: Is your motor AC or DC? 5 V AC would be unusual. Power in = Power out is exactly what you want. So for 5 V @ 2 A out you need 240 V @ 41.6 mA from the mains. The power supply won't be 100% efficient so it will probably require more like 80 mA or so at 240 V AC.

Comment: Hi,so a transformer will extract the power that it needs, you mean to say that if I connect a 50 coils input and a 50 coils output transformer, it will light up an LED without bursting it because I have seen in some videos of them connecting LED to socket using this transformer method and burst it?

Comment: (1) You didn't clarify whether the motor is AC or DC. (2) No I don't mean anything about 50 turn : 50 turn transformers and LEDs. Study how transformers work from books or proper electronics tutorials. Transformers transform voltages by the turns ratio. 240:5 would require a turns ratio of, perhaps, 2400:50 or thereabouts, not 50:50 which would give the same output as input.